# When trying to add a Custom app to a SharePoint 2013 on-premise I get the error "You need Office Development tools to create a site"

Tags: .net, sharepoint

I am trying to get a SharePoint 2013 application WebPart working compiled with Visual Studio 2019. First, I have added the custom app to the SharePoint catalog but under the header "Valid App Package" column the value is No. Second when I create a Farm Collection and try to Build an app I get the error message "You need Office Development tools to create a site". I have looked for the download but can't find one. Has anyone experienced this same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you installed the tool for SharePoint development.

[image]